# Simple HTML DOM parser not updating

Tags: php, simple-html-dom, domparser

I'm using the simple HTML DOM parser for my own template system and found a problem.

Here's my markup:

```
<div class=content>
    <div class=navigation></div>
</div>
```

I'm replacing the div.navigation with own content like:

```
$navi= $dom->find("div.navigation",0);
$navi->outertext = "<a class=aNavi>click me!</a>";
```

works nicely - i can echo it but the problem is - before echoing i still want to access/manipulate that link with the parser, but the parser won't find it.

```
$link = $dom->find("a.aNavi");
```

will return null :(

Seems like the parser needs to be refreshed/updated after changing the outertext - any ideas if it's possible?

Comment: Because your `a.aNavi` not in DOM. It is just some element of the separate object (or instance).

Comment: but it's in the source .. how could i fix it?

Comment: What exactly is `$dom`?  It doesn't appear to be a [DOMDocument](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php), as that class has no `find()` method or `outertext` property.

Comment: @drrcknlsn: I think OP is using http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/ instead of DOMDocument

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see any `createElement`-like method in [the API reference](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual_api.htm), which means either the documentation is incomplete or you're using the wrong tool for the job.

**I suggest using [DOMDocument](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php), and the [DOMDocument::createElement()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.createelement.php) method**.  However, if you're dead set on using Simple HTML DOM Parser, you could try this hack:

```
$navi = $dom->find('div.navigation', 0);
$navi->outertext = '<a class="aNavi">click me!</a>';
$dom = $dom->save();
$dom = str_get_html($dom);
$link = $dom->find('a.aNavi');
```

Comment: yes i already did that but it's dirty :)
as i'm still at the beginning i guess it's better using DOMDocument - thanks!